# How to resolve CVEs in spring-batch-core 4.0.1.RELEASE?

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, spring-batch, pom.xml

I noticed that I cannot create an issue on the spring-batch github and I could not create a topic on the Spring forum so I was redirected here.

I have this in my `pom.xml` file as explained on [Spring.io's Batch tutorial](https://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And when I run the `mvn dependency-check:check` I see these issues

#### spring-tx-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar

- [CVE-2018-1199](https://pivotal.io/security/cve-2018-1199) - upgrade spring framework to latest 4.x

#### spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar

- [CVE-2014-0225](https://pivotal.io/security/cve-2014-0225) - upgrade spring mvc - added it and latest 4.x
- [CVE-2015-5211](https://pivotal.io/security/cve-2015-5211) - upgrade springframework 4.x
- [CVE-2016-5007](https://pivotal.io/security/cve-2016-5007) - upgrade springframework 4.x
- [CVE-2014-3578](https://pivotal.io/security/cve-2014-3578) - upgrade springframework 4.x
- [CVE-2014-3625](https://pivotal.io/security/cve-2014-3625) - upgrade springframework 4.x

I ran `mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt` the offending jars above are located in my classpath. Then ran 'mvn dependency:tree` but did not see the offending jars.

```
mvn dependency:tree 2>&1 | egrep -i 'batch-core|spring-tx'
```

I tried googling some of the core CVEs which said to upgrade spring-mvc which I don't even have in my project but I explicitly defined it anyway. My spring version is set to the latest 4.x and even upgrading to 5.x still throws the vulnerability because spring-batch-core's latest version is still vulnerable.

Am I doing something wrong in my pom file?

Comment: You have to show your dependencies part of your `pom.xml`. You wrote *My spring version is set to the latest 4.x* that means your are not using the transitive dependencies of `spring-batch-core`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, none of those CVEs apply directly to Spring Batch or the `spring-batch-core` jar file.  They are all related to Spring Framework and Spring MVC.  Also, every one of those CVEs has been mitigated in the specified patch versions.

If you have confirmed that your POM is bringing in the correct, non-vunlerable, version of Spring Framework, this is a case of a false positive and you'll need to configure whatever tool you're using to address this.  If the artifact you are building as a result of the build process includes a vulnerable version of Spring Framework (or related components), then you do have an issue with your POM.  We can help, but we need to see the POM in order to do so.

Comment: If I remove `spring-batch-core`, then `mvn dependency-check` doesn't complain. I couldn't find any resources online of anyone else mentioning the above CVEs with the dependency in question so I found this alarming especially since I don't use spring-mvc. I do use some packages of the spring framework. How can you be so sure that these false positives?

Comment: If the jars that are impacted are not in your classpath, they are false positives.  But that's what I'm specifically asking you to verify.

Comment: Thanks for helping me through this. I outputted my classpath and included the command in the above post. The 2 offending jars containing the CVEs are in my classpath.

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer Use `mvn dependency:tree` to see how the JARs are included in your project.

Comment: @dur interesting. It did not show `spring-tx` or `spring-batch-core`. Is that enough proof to suppress the warnings?

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer If you have a dependency `spring-batch-core`in your POM, you should see that dependency in your dependency tree, too.